# Net Force regarding Impulse and Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

I'm just going to preface this with: I don't know much, I've just started learning about impulse.

Question: If there is a change in velocity regarding momentum $P$ then would there be a net force on impulse: $F*\delta t $? because I'm assuming there will be acceleration. (hope this question makes sense)

Comment: Yes, that's Newton's 2nd law.

Answer (score 0):

A change in momentum $\vec p$ is what we call Impulse $\vec J$:

$$\vec J=\Delta \vec p$$

Now, set up Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum \vec F=\frac{\Delta \vec p} {\Delta t}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \sum \vec F \Delta t=\Delta \vec p \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \sum \vec F \Delta t=\vec J $$

So, yes, a change in velocity means a change in momentum, which means both that a nonzero total force is present and that an impulse is transferred.

Comment: Got it, Thnx! Also wondering how the relation between (inelastic and elastic collisions) if the momentum is conserved? Like how is Kinetic Energy related to this?

Comment: @GoofyWayne I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Both the momentum conservation law and the energy conservation law always hold true. But sometimes they can be hard to use. In an *elastic* collision (as a tennis ball bouncing off of a wall) both laws are easy to use. In an *inelastic* collision, some energy is being lost (energy spent to deform materials, energy lost as heat etc.). It is very hard to know how much, so it is very hard to add up all energy terms and use the energy conservation law. It is still easy to add up all momentum terms, though, so that law is still easy to use.

Comment: cool Thnx so much ;]